# need compare the days between sql and System.datetime

Tags: sql-server

in sql server 2012 i cant not give data type for days like sunday monday , and my project need compare the days between sql and System which contains days like sunday, monday... , please help me how can i proceed ahead?

Comment: If you show some example data, the query you're trying to do, and what you expect the results to look like then perhaps someone can help you.

Answer (score -1):

Try the following query:

```
SELECT CASE 
           WHEN CAST(dateX AS DATE) != CAST(dateY AS DATE) 
           then  'NOT EQUEL'
           else  'EQUEL'
```